# Calculating the total clock cycles per instruction in a CPU

Tags: mips, cpu, pipeline

I was reading some university material, and I found that to calculate the CPI (clock cycles per instruction) of a CPU, we use the following formula:

> CPI = Total execution cycles / executed instructions count

this is clear and does make sense, but for this example it says that `n` instructions have been executed:

```
instruction type   frequency     relative CPI
1                      50%            3
2                      20%            4
3                      30%            5
```

why is the total CPI equal to `3*0.5+4*0.2+5*0.3 = 3.8` and not `3.8/3 = 1.26` because following the above formula, there are a total of 3 executed instructions, or am I understanding the formula in a wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula is correct but you are not reading the table right.

```
instruction type   frequency     relative CPI
1                      50%            3
2                      20%            4
3                      30%            5
```

The first line means you have an instruction that uses 3 CPI and this instruction has a frequency of 50% which basically means every second instruction in your program is this instruction.

Instruction 2 needs 4 CPI to be executed but occurs only 20% in your program. 
Instruction 3 needs 5 CPI but occurs 30%.

Therefore you calculate `0.5 * 3 + 0.2 * 4 + 0.3 + 5 = 3.8`.
**It is basically the average CPI.**

---

Just imagine you have following program:

```
INS_1   3 CPI
INS_3   5 CPI
INS_1   3 CPI
INS_3   5 CPI
INS_2   4 CPI
INS_1   3 CPI
INS_3   5 CPI
INS_2   4 CPI
INS_1   3 CPI
INS_1   3 CPI 
--------------
       38 CPI / 10 (Instructions) = 3.8
```

Comment: What if after some optimization, the frequeny of the instructions of type 1 are now only `40%`, where does the other `10%` go ?

Comment: This means that you could remove 10% of you instructions. In the example in my answer this would mean that you were able to remove 1 of the 5 INS_1 which gets you a total of 9 instructions. By rearanging your instructions those 10% weren't needed anymore without changing the functionality of your program.

Comment: @aniani2020 if you optimize, you will have for example 40%-25%-35%. Which is basic percentage calculation, given your all your instructions are always 100%.

Comment: @TheFreddy1404 why did you add 5% to each of the other two instructions? why not for example: 40%-30%-30%, is there a rule to follow?

Comment: @aniani2020 There are two (general) ways to optimize here, either you throw instructions away, or you transform a slow instruction into *for example* two fast ones. Both change the percentage. Above I just stated a possible example. The exact values are up to the rules of maths.